# Update Component when Array Modified

Tags: reactjs

Before reading, please note that I am a React beginner.

I am trying to create a bare-bones version of a small project that I am about to start. I want to include a search bar that updates its results with every keystroke. Currently, I update an array named `search_results` with accurate search results on every keystroke in a component named **SearchBar**, and I've already wrote some code for displaying the results in a component named **SearchResults**, but I cannot figure out how to refresh the frontend alongside the function that handles keystrokes as the functions are in two seperate components.

SearchBar:

```js
function SearchBar() {
    const input_ref = React.useRef(null)


    function handleInputKeypress(event) {
        search_results = []
        const value = input_ref.current.value
        const regex = RegExp(value)

        movies.forEach(movie => {
            if (regex.test(movie.name)) {
                search_results.push(movie)
            }
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className="searchbar bg-secondary flex align-center">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} className="color-primary" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" autoComplete="off" onKeyUp={handleInputKeypress} ref={input_ref}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

SearchResults:

```js
function SearchResults() {
    return (
        <div className="searchresults bg-secondary flex align-center flex-col">
            {search_results.map(function(movie, index){
                    return <SearchResult imageSrc={movie.imageSrc}
                                         name={movie.name}
                                         desc={movie.desc}
                                         key={`search_result_${index}`}
                                         idx={index} />
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

And these are how they are arranged in a **Nav** component:

```js
class Nav extends Component {
    render() { 
        return (
            <nav className="flex align-center justify-center">
                <SearchBar />
                <SearchResults />
            </nav>
        );
    }
}
```

I tried looking into using React Hooks, but realized that it probably wouldn't be possible since they would need to be used in the same component.

I've also seen methods that use **props**, but because of how my app is constructed, I don't think it would be possible.

I've noticed Redux, but im not 100% sure about what it is or if it will help with this problem.

If it is required, these are some blocks of code that might help.

```js
var movies = [
    {
        imageSrc: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BN2VjOTkwMjgtYWEyMy00MzNmLTllMjktNDI1ZmRhYTAwYTg1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjAwNDUxODI@._V1_FMjpg_UX1000_.jpg",
        name: "Breaking Bad",
        desc: "Mild-mannered high school chemistry teacher Walter White thinks his life can't get much worse."
    },
    {
        imageSrc: "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/topgun/images/6/66/Top_Gun_Maverick_Poster_2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20191215142513",
        name: "Top Gun Maverick",
        desc: "After thirty years, Maverick is still pushing the envelope as a top naval aviator, but must confront ghosts of his past when he leads TOP GUN's elite graduates on a mission that demands the ultimate sacrifice from those chosen to fly it."
    }, 
]
```

```js
function SearchResult(props) {
    return (
        <div className="searchresult flex" style={{animationDelay: `${props.idx*50}ms`}}>
            <img src={props.imageSrc}/>
            <div className="info flex flex-col">
                <span className="name color-primary">{props.name}</span>
                <span className="desc color-secondary">{props.desc}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use useState for this.
[doc](https://initialcommit.com/blog/usestate-useeffect-hooks-react)

Try once with following code:

```
function Nav {
  const input_ref = React.useRef(null);
  const[searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

  function handleInputKeypress(event) {
        const search_results = []
        const value = input_ref.current.value
        const regex = RegExp(value)

        movies.forEach(movie => {
            if (regex.test(movie.name)) {
                search_results.push(movie)
            }
        });

        setSearchResults(search_results);
    }

  return (
    <nav className="flex align-center justify-center">
        <SearchBar input_ref={input_ref} handleInputKeypress={handleInputKeypress}/>
        <SearchResults search_results={searchResults}/>
    </nav>
  );
}

//SearchBar
function SearchBar({input_ref, handleInputKeypress}) {
    return (
        <div className="searchbar bg-secondary flex align-center">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} className="color-primary" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" autoComplete="off" onKeyUp={handleInputKeypress} ref={input_ref}/>
        </div>
    );
}

//SearchResult
function SearchResults({sea) {
    return (
             <div className="searchresults bg-secondary flex align-center flex-col">
              {search_results.map(function (movie, index) {
                return <SearchResult
                         imageSrc={movie.imageSrc}
                         name={movie.name}
                         desc={movie.desc}
                         key={`search_result_${index}`}
                         idx={index} 
                      />
             })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work! Thank you so much.